# How to determine whether an integral is convergent

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I missed up the last lecture and can't understand how to determine whether an integral with parameters is convergent or divergent?

**For example:** For which values of the parameters $p,q \in [0,\infty)$, the following integral is convergent

$$
 \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^p + x^q}.
$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/convdiv/convdiv.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without loss of generality we suppose $p\geq q$ then
$$\frac{1}{x^p+x^q}=\frac{1}{x^q(x^{p-q}+1)}=\frac{1}{x^p(x^{q-p}+1)},\tag{1}$$
then there's two possible cases:

*Case $p>q$:* from the first equality of $(1)$
$$\frac{1}{x^p+x^q}\sim_0\frac{1}{x^q},$$
so $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}$ is convergent $\iff$ $q<1$, and from the second equality of $(1)$
$$\frac{1}{x^p+x^q}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{x^p},$$
so $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}$ is convergent $\iff$ $p>1$,
hence
 $$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q} \mathrm{is\, convergent} \iff 0\leq q<1<p.$$
*Case $p=q$:* it's easy to see that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}$ is divergent.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understood it :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $x^a$ is integrable near $x=0$ when $a>-1$ and $x^b$ is integrable as $x \rightarrow \infty$ when $b < -1$.

$$\int_0^r dx \: x^a = \frac{r^{a+1} - 0^{a+1}}{a+1}$$

Note that if $a+1<0$, then the numerator is infinite (i.e., 1/0).  If $a+1=0$, then the denominator is zero.  So $a+1>0$ for convergence at $x=0$.

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}\int_r^{s} dx \: x^b= \lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}\frac{s^{b+1}-r^{b+1}}{b+1}$$

For the limit to exist in the numerator, $b+1<0$.  If $b+1=0$, then the denominator is infinite.  So $b+1<0$ for convergence at infinity.

Comment: Hi, thank for the fast answer. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Noting some valuable points as hints besides to @Ron's answer:

- $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^p + x^q}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^p + x^q}+\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^p + x^q}$
- $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ converges if $p<1$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}(x-a)^pf(x)=A$ is finite.
- $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ diverges if $p\geq1$ and $A\neq 0$ ($A$ may be infinite).
- $\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges if $p>1$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}x^pf(x)=A$ is finite.
- $\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges if $p\leq1$ and $A\neq 0$ ($A$ may be infinite).

Comment: I hope I could help. ;-)

Comment: Of course you can help, and this will help future visitors as well! +1